# Why changing %rbp doesn't crash Assembly?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-registers, att

I was testing the following assembly code:

```
.data
msg1: .ascii "HOW YOOOU DOOIN?"
msg2: .ascii "JOEY DOESN'T SHARE FOOD!"
msg1_len: .quad msg2-msg1
msg2_len: .quad msg1_len-msg2
all_msg_len: .quad msg1_len-msg1

.text
.global main

main:

  mov $msg1, %rsi
  mov $1, %rdi
  mov $1, %rdx
  mov $1, %rax
  mov $0, %rbx
  mov all_msg_len, %r9
  call exm


exm:
  cmp %rbx, %r9
  je end
  addb $0x20, (%rsi)
  test $1, %rbx
  jnz skip
  syscall

skip:
  inc %rsi
  inc %rbx
  call exm

end:
  ret
```

I changed the 2 usages of register r9 with register rbp and my code worked fine. why is that?

Isn't rbp a pointer to the base of the stack's frame? I expected that changing its value would cause a catastrophic but it seems my expectations were wrong. why is that?

Comment: `rbp` is intended for use as a stack frame pointer. However, this is optional, you can use it as a GPR. Unlike `rsp` there are no push, pop, call, return instructions which implicitly use `rbp`. Only `enter` and `leave`, and explicit uses of `rbp`, which you do not use in your example.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't rbp a pointer to the base of the stack's frame?

The `%rbp` register only becomes *special* once you start using it for function prologue/epilogue. Your *exm* doesn't use it that way and so the `%rbp` register is no different from `%r9`.

Comment: In the x86-64 System V calling convention, RBP is call-preserved like RBX but R9 is call-clobbered like RCX, so in general they're different.  So `main` overwriting RBP would violate the ABI in general, but apparently main's caller on this system doesn't depend on main preserving RBP.  (Probably main's caller just call's `exit` directly instead of doing another level of return, IIRC what glibc's CRT code does.)  Of course, this code is already violating the ABI by destroying RBX.

Comment: (Last question with this code, it was under `_start`, not `main`, but without `.global _start` and with a `.ascii` string before it in .text so it couldn't actually work as-is.  Not to mention that it also crashed from trying to ret from _start.  This is probably the real version.)